# How to count number of days between multiple flagged dates and categories

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Attempting to count how many days, on average, it takes work to get done on a vehicle after it has been flagged as being due, sorted by each work code : MTP, FSV, DOT. For example, MTP has been due for 9 days for vehicle # X. It was only due for 1 day for vehicle # Y. For those vehicles, MTP is done after being due for 5 consecutive days.

When a work code is due, a column fills with 'D'.
Vehicles will have multiple FSV, MTP, and DOT work done in their lifespan.
Records are updated daily.

```
SELECT vehicle, work_code, record_update_date, work_is_due
FROM table
where work_code IN ('MTP', 'FSV', 'DOT')
AND work_is_due = 'D' `
```

I think I need to take each vehicle and concatenate that field with the work code - for example, vehicle 20,000 and MTP work category would show up as 20000MTP. I'm not sure how to handle the fact that it will have several MTPs performed in its lifespan. If it was just one instance, I think I could do a datediff function for the MIN and MAX dates that were flagged as 'D'.

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be helpful here. [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And also add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: This sounds like a simple group by work_code that shows an average number of days. No need for concatenation. No need to worry about reporting same vehicle more than once. Show how you would calculate days, as that seems to be the sticky point for giving an answer.

Comment: so there is a edge variable `work_is_due = 'D'` that becomes true when we want to start counting, and it is cleared when the service is done? How does a vehicle sericed on the day it's due be encoded, and how does a vehicle service the day before due get encoded?